# Sleeping in sleeping bag at Helsinki Vantaa airport

Tags: airports, sleeping, hel

I’m going to have a trip through Helsinki Vantaa airport in June 2017. I will arrive late in the evening, but my train won’t leave until early the next morning, so I need to spend one night somehow.

I’m considering taking a sleeping bag and sleeping somewhere in the airport. I have been there 5 years ago and have seen some people doing so.

My questions are:

- Is it still possible to sleep in sleeping bag in Helsinki Vantaa airport?
- Would I be the only one doing so?
- Does airport work 24h?

Comment: You can find [reviews of HEL](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/helsinki.htm) at SleepinginAirports.net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the airport works 247. I just recently spent a night there last week and I can guarantee you will not be the only one. As the airport was renovated recently, there's now less places to sleep on the benches. For 247 amenities there is at least a 247 grocery store and the Burger King is also open quite late, not sure if 247.

Note that if you don't have checked-in luggage I would recommend staying airside for the night. It's a lot more comfortable and it will be easy to find a place to sleep and to charge your phone.

Comment: Lassi, thanks for your response! So, there is now less places to sleep on the benches, but it is still possible to sleep in sleeping bag on the floor, right?

Comment: Sure, lots of floor space that's perfectly fine for sleeping